# javascript html editor copy/paste problem

Tags: php, javascript, tinymce

We run some large directories where users often copy/paste content from word documents etc into our TinyMCE html editor.

The problem with this is often the following text for example gets hidden there which shows up on our webpages:

```
<!-- /* Style Definitions */ p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal {mso-style-parent:""; margin:0in; margin-bottom:.0001pt; mso-pagination:widow-orphan; mso-layout-grid-align:none; punctuation-wrap:simple; text-autospace:none; font-size:10.0pt; font-family:"Times New Roman"; mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";} a:link, span.MsoHyperlink {color:blue; text-decoration:underline; text-underline:single;} a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed {color:purple; text-decoration:underline; text-underline:single;} p {mso-margin-top-alt:auto; margin-right:0in; mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto; margin-left:0in; mso-pagination:widow-orphan; font-size:12.0pt; font-family:"Times New Roman"; mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";} @page Section1 {size:8.5in 11.0in; margin:1.0in 1.25in 1.0in 1.25in; mso-header-margin:.5in; mso-footer-margin:.5in; mso-paper-source:0;} div.Section1 {page:Section1;} -->
```

Is there a TinyMCE plugin or some other cross browser html editor that automatically strip this out?

Or another solution would be some php regex command or something that could strip out these comment declarations.

Comment: Best of luck with this one.  I've looked and looked and looked and haven't found anything, but I am watching this post like a hawk, hoping someone has a better solution than manually using Dreamweaver to clean up Word's mess.

Comment: Try ckeditor at http://ckeditor.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [tinymce and importing / copy paste from microsoft word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255738/tinymce-and-importing-copy-paste-from-microsoft-word)

Comment: TinyMCE seems to have a "paste from Word" functionality, like other WYSIWYG editors as well. See the duplicate.

Comment: To add onto to Pekka's comment, I've also seen TinyMCE set the Paste from word as a default behavior on paste when used in Drupal. Seems likely that's it is a TinyMCE feature being exposed by Drupal not a Drupal extra.

Comment: problem is no one ever uses that option, I've even put a bold line above the text editor telling them to do that but of course they still don't :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been trying to optimize on that one for years.

My best solution so far goes like this:

- don't use a root block, the layout will implement the root layout
- don't expect the user to understand the difference between `<p>` and `<br />` and therefor treat everything as a simple break as it is less confusing and more ms-word-like
- only allow expected elements

This would be the **init code**.

```
remove_linebreaks : false,
force_br_newlines : true, <?php /* maybe we can behave more like gmail */ ?>
force_p_newlines : false,   <?php /* and preserve all message line breaks */ ?> 
convert_newlines_to_brs : false, <?php /* even so i would not count with it */ ?>
forced_root_block : false

<?php /* explicitly define what will be allowed */ ?>
valid_elements: "h1,h2,h3,br,b,a,i,u,strong/b,em/i,u/span,strike/span,span,span[style],"+
                "sub,sup,a[href|name|anchor|target|title],ul,ol,li,p,object[classid|width|height|codebase|*],"+
                "param[name|value|_value],embed[type|width|height|src|*],"+
                "img[style|longdesc|usemap|src|border|alt=|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align]",
```

And then I have the following post-process function to remove all `<p>` and convert all `</p>` to `<br /><br />` this has been the most **stable** copy-paste solution I've been able to dev.

This is the **post-process function**:

```
setup : function(ed) {
    ed.onPostProcess.add(function(ed, o) {
        // Remove all paragraphs and replace with BR
        o.content = o.content.replace(/<p [^>]+>|<p>/g, '');
        o.content = o.content.replace(/<\/p>/g, '<br />');
    });
},
```

Do notice that all this is just Javascript filtering and the user will be able to pass all that non-desired code to the server in a snap. Even though this setup is probably intended for end-admin setups also use `strip_tags` on the server side as someone somewhere will probably be able to by-pass-it.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

The PHP regex command is what I'd use, personally.

```
$str = preg_replace('/<!--.*?--\>/','',$str);
```

Comment: perfect, will give this a shot