# Paste from Word to TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, tinymce

I am trying to allow my users to paste content from word processors (MS Word, Open Office..) and have it process the garbage markup into valid html.

Here is a fiddle for my code: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/xLeaab

I want to preserve:

- bold, italic, strike through *(done)*
- tables and lists *(done)*
- font color, text highlight and alignment *(please help)*

FYI - I've been looking at these questions on Stackoverflow as part of my current solution, however Im not the best with RegEx so Im having a hard time:

- [TinyMCE Paste As Plain Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122451/tinymce-paste-as-plain-text)
- [RegEx to remove all styles but leave color and background-color if they exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412388/regex-to-remove-all-styles-but-leave-color-and-background-color-if-they-exist)
- [Regex: match everything but](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687620/regex-match-everything-but)

Comment: Can you post an example of "__garbage markup__" ?

Comment: @PedroLobito, OP refers to "garbage markup" bc word uses a superset of html, open xml, and rte formats. So when pasting from word to HTML, as much as preserving proper markup, extra or "garbage markup" must be removed.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1255786/797495), it may be a good start for you

Comment: @PedroLobito, you have the right idea, but Rachel is using the **paste plugin** and is trying to properly configure `paste_word_valid_elements`. Her Fiddle already takes care of many of her desires. Just font-color, highlight, and alignment are not rendered properly.

Comment: I never got a response from you about my solution. Did you get a chance to try it? Did it fall short? If so, in what ways?

Answer (score 23):

I think I have it, **[Check Fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/6Leaab/1)**

**Confirmed:**

- Text alignment
- Fonts
- Colors
- Highlights

---

**My changes:**

**1)** commented out your `paste_postprocess` *(it was sanitizing styles)*

```
    //paste_postprocess: function(plugin, args) {
    //    args.node.innerHTML = cleanHTML(args.node.innerHTML);
    //},
```

**2)** defined a set of `paste_word_valid_elements` in init *(the allowed list)*

```
    paste_word_valid_elements: "b,strong,i,em,h1,h2,u,p,ol,ul,li,a[href],
          span,color,font-size,font-color,font-family,mark",
```

**3)** set paste retain style be to "all" *(if you want to be selective, create a custom list)*

```
     paste_retain_style_properties: "all",
```

:

---

**Fiddle Screen Shot**

[image]

Comment: @rachelc, I never heard back what was wrong with my example. I could have worked on whatever deficiency you found...

Comment: `paste_word_valid_elements` has been deprecated as of TinyMCE version 5.10 and removed in version 6.0. Now there seems only to be the `PowerPaste` plugin provided as a premium feature for paid cloud plans.

Answer (score 0):

**WordPress TinyMCE Users:**

[Dave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30041651/10319568) above solved my issue with this implementation in WordPress:

(using TinyMCE plugin and Advanced ***TinyMCE Configuration*** plugin)

Use the following TinyMCE Config overrides:

**Name : Value**

keep_styles : true

paste_retain_style_properties : true

[Image: The settings page implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Hpt6.png)

Big thanks to [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30041651/10319568).